# protractor browser.executescript does not return a value

Tags: protractor

I'm trying to run the following scripts in Protractor

```
browser.executeScript("return window.localStorage.getItem('access_token');").then((accessToken) => {
                            console.log("AccessToken Obtained ", accessToken);
                        });
```

However the code never goes into the .then section.  It just gets blocked.  I tried  executeAsyncScript and still the same result.

I went through a lot of online examples and I think this should work, however not sure whats going wrong here.

Comment: Run `window.localStorage.getItem('access_token');` in browser DevTool's console manually to see it work or not.

Comment: yes I tried it on dev tools, and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this one:

```
function getAccessToken() {
  return window.localStorage.getItem('access_token');
}

browser.executeScript(getAccessToken).then((accessToken) => {
  console.log("AccessToken Obtained ", accessToken);
});
```